# CSS file is not affecting my HTML or not loading without copying the FULL path

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link my CSS file to my html file and it is not linking without a Full path. They are on the same level, and I don't get the effect specified in the CSS file. The simple code in CSS is
body { background-color: blue; }
Thank you in advance for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwBC8.png)

Comment: You have to get out of **Web Dev..** and **Notebook..** folder first to access **CSS** folder. Try using `../../css/styles.css`

Comment: Hello. You should provide code, so we can reproduce your issue. My guess is that you entered invalid relative path, which should be ../style.css I think.
EDIT: Didnt notice the img provided, the path is as Debsmita wrote...

Comment: Thank you, it worked for the answer
href="../css/styles.css"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I can see in the screenshot, the HTML and the CSS are **not in the same folder**. If you want to link to a CSS file that is in a higher directory you should use **../**.

In your case, your code should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/styles.css">
```

**Note:** Please paste your code in your post instead of making a screenshot, it makes it harder for people to copy / edit things.

Comment: Will do for your note sorry. It is not working, but it is working only with the full path copied from the file.
I am following along with a course online and it worked perfectly in the course.
The option provided didn't work sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not in the same directory as your css file. To achieve the desired reult, you will have to go up 2 directories and then access the file through the css folder.